# HashMap gives me last data only

Tags: java, android, listview, hashmap

The main motive of this programme to display some data from SQLite in android ListView.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new Dictionary(contex);
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();

            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);
            String word = et.getText().toString();
            wordlist = new ArrayList<>();

            String query = "SELECT ID, WORD" +
                    " FROM E_DICT WHERE WORD LIKE '"+word+"%' ORDER BY WORD ASC LIMIT 100 ";
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
                if(cursor!=null){
                    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                        do{

                            long a = cursor.getLong(0);
                            String b = cursor.getString(1);

                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put(EDICT_WORD, b);
                            map.put(EDICT_ID, ""+a);
                            Log.d("RESULT", a +" " + b); //Till this this like everything seems to be ok.
                            wordlist.add(map);
                        }
                        while(cursor.moveToNext());

                    }}
            return null;
        }
```

Now I load my data in some `AsyncTask<String, String, String>` like this:

```
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            Main.this, wordlist, R.layout.word_list,
                            new String[] {EDICT_WORD, EDICT_ID},
                            new int[] {R.id.eDict_Word, R.id.eDict_Id});
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
```

This gives me the last `EDICT_ID` only as listview output. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many data you have in your database? And, how many items wordlist have?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are always creating new HashMap, and return that with only one value added.

So, move your HashMap from

```
if(cursor!=null){
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    ....
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    while(cursor.moveToNext());
}}
```

To outside of loop.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
if(cursor!=null){
    ....
}
```

Comment: But the HashMaps are being added to `wordList`, which is a list of maps.